# Get the last part of a URL from a Youtube embed code

Tags: php

I woud like to get the last part of a Youtube URL from an embed code such as:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gaDa2Zgtqo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The part I am trying to get is `gaDa2Zgtqo`

I have tried using the explode e.g.

```
$string = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gaDa2Zgtqo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
$exploded = explode('/', $string);
echo $exploded[2]
```

but this results in `www.youtube.com` and nothing else.

Is there another approach I can use?

Comment: Use `$exploded[4]`, and take it from there? (`".. and the rest` is still in there). Or use a DOM parser, get the attribute, parse path part out of the url, and explode that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$string = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gaDa2Zgtqo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
preg_match('/(?<=\/embed\/)[^"\']*/', $string,$matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump($exploded);` gives you this information:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http:' (length=43)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string 'www.youtube.com' (length=15)
  3 => string 'embed' (length=5)
  4 => string 'gaDa2Zgtqo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen><' (length=45)
  5 => string 'iframe>' (length=7)
```

So we see the necessary string is in the 5th element of the array. We need the first 10 characters of it.

```
echo substr($exploded[4], 0, 10);
// gaDa2Zgtqo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the regex way

```
$str = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gaDa2Zgtqo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
preg_match_all('/src="[^"]+?\/([^\/"]+)"/', $str, $x);
var_dump($x);
```

it will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gaDa2Zgtqo"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => gaDa2Zgtqo
        )
)
```

so your desired string is at `$x[1][0]`

If you have other elements in the HTML string that have src attribute, e.g., `<img>` then you can use following regular expression

```
preg_match_all('/<iframe[^>]+src="[^"]+?\/([^\/"]+)"/', $str, $x);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the URL format is always this then why not use:

```
$string = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gaDa2Zgtqo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
preg_match("/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/", $string, $matches);
$id = $matches[1];
//$id = gaDa2Zgtqo
```